# Accessing a single PHP file from two different activites in android

Tags: java, php, android

I have two activites: `Mainpage.java` and `Secondary.java`. And I am trying to access the same php file from both the class. When the second class is called the following ***error*** is revoked.

```
  java.lang.nullpointerexception.
```

How can i remove this error?

This is causing the apllication to force close.
Thanks.
This the code for the first class:
    void login(){
       try{

```
       httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();

       httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/ABC/login.php"); 
       nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));  
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim()));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action","LOGIN"));

       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

       ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
       response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
       final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
       System.out.println("Response : " + response);


               tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);

               if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found"))
               {
                   Toast.makeText(Axdroid.this,"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

                   startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Secondary.class));
               }                   else
               {
                    showAlert();     
               }                                     

       dialog.dismiss();   


   }catch(Exception e){

       System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
   }
```

}

And this for the secondary class
    void jsr(){

```
    try{
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/AndroidLeave/login.php");
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action","SUMMARY"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        System.out.println(" ++++++++  +++++++++++++"+response);                    

        entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }

    System.out.println(" ++++++++ After getting data from PHP file +++++++++++++");

    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line="0";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());}
    }}
```

LOGCAT:

```
 10-26 18:10:01.313: W/SingleClientConnManager(2296): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
 10-26 18:10:01.964: E/log_tag(2296): Error in http connectionjava.lang.NullPointerException
 10-26 18:10:01.974: E/log_tag(2296): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: You have to show some code.. How you access the page in both activity? also please provide the logcat output

Comment: have provided kindly have a look

Comment: I'm having troubles understanding what you're doing in the first class. You call `response=httpclient.execute(httppost);` I assume `response` is `HttpResponse`, but then you make another call using the `ResponseHandler`. why are you making 2 calls?

Comment: Also, if you could post the complete logcat output, it would help, if none of the answers helped you yet

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because you try to initiate the second connection, but you didn't close the first one.
Since you didn't use and `InputStream` in the first class, you didn't call, like in the second one, `is.close()`.

I don't quite understand why, in the first class, you make two calls to `execute()`.

You could do this:
delete these two lines

```
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

and after this line

```
response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

add:

```
final String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

then use `responseString` where ever you use `response` as a `String`.
If it still happening, add after that
    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
the `toString` shoud do the consume as well, but just in case it doesn't.

If it still doestn' work, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Just quickly looking at your code, the exception is probably occurring on this line in  the second class:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action","SUMMARY"));
```

because `nameValuePairs` is null. You might try adding something like:

```
nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
```

before you try calling `nameValuePairs.add()`

Comment: But then it would have thrown the NullPointerException in that line.

Comment: @Lablabla Um, no. In this case, the user has made that call inside a `try/catch` block where he is catching all `Exception`s. Since `NullPointerException` is also an `Exception`, the error is caught in the `catch` block and the stack trace is not written to the logcat.

Comment: You're right. missed that part. Since we don't have the complete logcat, you might be right and it's much simpler than what my answer addresses.